# ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session' omit WSUS?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I'm trying to get information about how up-to-date is windows systems. Information from `systemstatus` or `wmic qfe list` sometimes don't give full list of installed hostfixs. So I want to make powershell script which checks if there is available updates for system. My scripts looks like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param ()

Begin {
    $UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'
}   

Process {
    $UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")

    if ($SearchResult.Updates.Count -ne 0) {
        $SearchResult.Updates |Select-Object -Property Title, Description |Format-List
    }   
    else {
        Write-Host 'There are no applicable updates'
    }   
}
```

My question is: Do this script checks for new updates from local WSUS or from Microsoft's servers?
My goal is: Check updates from Microsoft's servers to omit situation, when WSUS's administrator will drop some important updates.

Comment: It's going to check against whatever the server is configured to use for WSUS.  You could stop the service, change the registry to point to MS, start the service again, perform your checks and then reverse the change, but it would probably be easier to just interrogate the WSUS server itself to see if there are any declined updates using this - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826166.aspx

Comment: I'm going to use this to audits my customers servers - as less changes I'll do on that servers it's better. And for now my script don't need admin privs - changing services would required that privs.

Comment: best options then would probably be to use the WSUS cmdlets to query the WSUS server directly for declined updates.  alternatively you could build your own DB of KB's that should be present and check against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a search like yours i found this... if it helps

```
Function Get-PendingUpdate { 
<#    
  .SYNOPSIS   
    Retrieves the updates waiting to be installed from WSUS   
  .DESCRIPTION   
    Retrieves the updates waiting to be installed from WSUS  
  .PARAMETER Computername 
    Computer or computers to find updates for.   
  .EXAMPLE   
   Get-PendingUpdates 

   Description 
   ----------- 
   Retrieves the updates that are available to install on the local system 
  .NOTES 
  Author: Boe Prox                                           

#> 

#Requires -version 3.0   
[CmdletBinding( 
    DefaultParameterSetName = 'computer' 
    )] 
param( 
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True)] 
        [string[]]$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )     
Process { 
    ForEach ($computer in $Computername) { 
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) { 
            Try { 
            #Create Session COM object 
                Write-Verbose "Creating COM object for WSUS Session" 
                $updatesession =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$computer)) 
                } 
            Catch { 
                Write-Warning "$($Error[0])" 
                Break 
                } 

            #Configure Session COM Object 
            Write-Verbose "Creating COM object for WSUS update Search" 
            $updatesearcher = $updatesession.CreateUpdateSearcher() 

            #Configure Searcher object to look for Updates awaiting installation 
            Write-Verbose "Searching for WSUS updates on client" 
            $searchresult = $updatesearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")     

            #Verify if Updates need installed 
            Write-Verbose "Verifing that updates are available to install" 
            If ($searchresult.Updates.Count -gt 0) { 
                #Updates are waiting to be installed 
                Write-Verbose "Found $($searchresult.Updates.Count) update\s!" 
                #Cache the count to make the For loop run faster 
                $count = $searchresult.Updates.Count 

                #Begin iterating through Updates available for installation 
                Write-Verbose "Iterating through list of updates" 
                For ($i=0; $i -lt $Count; $i++) { 
                    #Create object holding update 
                    $Update = $searchresult.Updates.Item($i)
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        #Computername = $Computer
                        KB = $($Update.KBArticleIDs)
                        Title = $Update.Title
                        Categories = ($Update.Categories | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
                        SecurityBulletin = $($Update.SecurityBulletinIDs)
                        MsrcSeverity = $Update.MsrcSeverity
                        IsDownloaded = $Update.IsDownloaded
                        Url = $($Update.MoreInfoUrls)
                        BundledUpdates = @($Update.BundledUpdates)|ForEach{
                           [pscustomobject]@{
                                Title = $_.Title
                                DownloadUrl = @($_.DownloadContents).DownloadUrl
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            } 
            Else { 
                #Nothing to install at this time 
                Write-Verbose "No updates to install." 
            }
        } 
        Else { 
            #Nothing to install at this time 
            Write-Warning "$($c): Offline" 
        }  
    }
}
```

}

thanks to Boe Prox... it is a great script!